# Alien invasion movie with bird hitting invisible wall

Tags: identify-this-movie, science-fiction

It was about some sort of aliens trying to enter earth. I was watching it on and off on TV so couldn't find more details.

Details:

1. They were broadcasting some stuff of what's happening on news or something. The lead actor's son or someone was watching it and seeing what was happening and was pretty freaked out. One of the scenes on TV was about how someone recorded a bird flying in mid air and stopped in the middle and fell down straight. He said this almost word for word "It was as if there was an invisible wall over there".
2. There were 2 kids, a girl around 6 and a boy around 8. The boy was reading some sort of book where they talked about aliens. He was taking about how there were 2 options with alien invasion if they came for resource. They invade, we win, and they come back 100 or 1000 years later. Or we lose. He also talked about how they will not do air strikes too much since they wouldn't want us to do nuclear attacks and make the planet useless.
3. This part is *really* fuzzy to me. The actor looked a little like Robert de niro but I don't think he was. I might have even gone crazy and he looked nothing like him.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9):

It sounds like your describing two - three different movies...

- (Small chance if not SIGNS) The Last Mimzy
- **Signs** (Has everything but the *Robert de niro*)

I would guess Signs because [WIKI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signs_(film))

> The **dead bird**: With no sound, this scene shows Graham going back home from Ray's, and after a short time, a dead bird near the road (**after supposedly hitting an invisible forcefield**) is shown.

And it is a Alien movie about an father, son, daughter, and uncle on a farm.
 [image: uncle, son, daughter] [image: father]. 
The key point in the movie for me was seeing **the book that Morgan Hess is using to predict how the alien invasion will develop**.

The [book he's reading](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20120219195454AA11ojJ/) from is a pastiche of [Linda Howes "Glimpses of Other Realities"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0962057053), in which she spins out sinister and lurid stories of aliens coming here, mutilating our animals, creating patterns in our crops and harvesting humans for food.

Comment: Don't remember bird scene but it looks like a match, +1.

Comment: Yeah I seem to remember another movie of birds hitting an invisible wall or force field. The kids reading abook I thought about Phenomenon (John Travolta) well the list goes on...

Comment: In this movie (Signs) there's a scene about a bird hit by an invisible wall force field.
Merrill (interpretated by Joaquin Phoenix) is watching TV in the closet and he shows to Mel Gibson the video where bird suddenly falls down.
So @Understood answer is right ;)

Comment: @MikeKeepsOnShine yup that scene is about 45mins in. I could not see anything but they talk about the bird hitting an invisible force field. 5mins later the son talks about aliens plan and the book.